# Proving a Language to be regular

Tags: regular-language

Pumping Lemma is used to prove a language to be not regular. But How a language can be
proved to be regular ? In particular,

```
Let L be a language. Define half(L) to be  
{ x | for some y such that |x| = |y|, xy is in L}.  
Prove for each regular L that half(L) is regular.
```

Is there any trick or general procedure to tackle such kind of questions ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can correctly describe your language L by an [NFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton) or [DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton), then it will be regular.

There is a well known equality of NFAs, DFAs, [regular grammars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) and [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), so a representation of L in any of these formalisms should do.

Answer (score 5):

Provide a regular grammar or a finite automaton that matches the language. For the full list of properties you can prove to show a language is regular, see the first lines of the [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) on regular languages.

Comment: +1 for forcing me to parse (bad pun intended) "[A Regular Language] is the preimage of a subset of a finite monoid under a homomorphism from the free monoid on its alphabet."

Comment: Luckily, you need to choose just one of those bullet points if you just want to prove a language to be regular.